# Merging one dataframe that has two date columns with another dataframe that has two date columns

Tags: pandas, join, filter, merge, pandas-groupby

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I can match dataframes that contain a two-column time range and some additional columns. I need to insert/match the `start_date` and `end_date` in Dataframe `A` to the observations in Dataframe `B`, `open_date` and `close_date`, along with matching `other_var` and `name`.

Here are the two dataframes that I have:

```
    A                                               B
    start_date  end_date    other_var   name            open_date   close_date   other_var   name
0   2018-05-01  2018-05-01  7H          companyB    0   2018-07-06  2019-02-17   1H          companyA   
1   2018-05-02  2018-05-04  1H          companyC    1   2018-07-13  2018-11-04   1H          companyB
2   2018-05-10  2018-05-11  2H          companyA    2   2018-04-23  2018-05-08   1H          companyB
3   2018-05-04  2018-05-09  1H          companyB    3   2018-04-05  2018-10-01   7H          companyB
                                                    4   2018-05-03  2018-06-01   1H          companyB
```

My desired output in a new dataframe (C) is:

```
    C                                               
    start_date  end_date    open_date   close_date   other_var   name 
0   2018-05-01  2018-05-01  2018-04-05  2018-10-01   7H          companyB
1   2018-05-04  2018-05-09  2018-05-03  2018-06-01   1H          companyB
```

Note, the order in dataframe C doesn't matter and the dataset I am working with is ~1000 rows with dates ranging from 2015-2019.

Any suggestions or help is very much appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: You can set column you want to match with as index. And then just merge by index two dataframes.

Comment: Why is there not a match with `start_date : 2018-05-04`, `end_date : 2018-05-09` and `open_date : 2018-04-05` and `close_date : 2018-10-01`.  The logic isn't clear.

Comment: @elPastor because the `other_var` is different between dataframe `A`and dataframe `B`. Therefore, no match. Thank you for looking into it still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest merging on `other_var` and `name` and then filtering by comparing datetime columns:

```
import pandas as pd
# Reproducing your data
dfa = pd.DataFrame({"start_date": ["2018-05-01", "2018-05-02", "2018-05-10", "2018-05-04"],
                    "end_date": ["2018-05-01", "2018-05-04", "2018-05-11", "2018-05-09"],
                    "other_var": ["7H", "1H", "2H", "1H"],
                    "name": ["companyB", "companyC", "companyA", "companyB"]})

dfb = pd.DataFrame({"open_date": ["2018-07-06", "2018-07-13", "2018-04-23", "2018-04-05", "2018-05-03"],
                    "close_date": ["2019-02-17", "2018-11-04", "2018-05-08", "2018-10-01", "2018-06-01"],
                    "other_var": ["1H", "1H", "1H", "7H", "1H"],
                    "name": ["companyA", "companyB", "companyB", "companyB", "companyB"]})

df = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on=["other_var", "name"])
df[["start_date", "end_date", "open_date", "close_date"]] = \
    df[["start_date", "end_date", "open_date", "close_date"]].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df = df.loc[(df["start_date"]>=df["open_date"]) & (df["end_date"]<=df["close_date"]),:]
```

The result is

```
  start_date   end_date other_var      name  open_date close_date
0 2018-05-01 2018-05-01        7H  companyB 2018-04-05 2018-10-01
3 2018-05-04 2018-05-09        1H  companyB 2018-05-03 2018-06-01
```